# Subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_n$, order divisibility

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that for any subgroups $H$ and $H'$ of $\mathbb{Z}_n$, $H \subseteq H'$ if and only if $|H|$ divides $|H'|$.

Attempt: If $H \subseteq \mathbb{Z}_n$, then for every positive divisor $q_1$ of $n$, the cardinality of $H$ is $q_1$, $q_1 = \langle[\frac{n}{q_1}]\rangle$.
So $H = \langle \frac{n}{q_1}\rangle$, where $|H| = q_1$.
Similarly, $H' = \langle \frac{n}{q_2}\rangle$ where $|H'|= q_2$. 
Suppose $H \subseteq H'$, then $H = \langle \frac{n}{q_1}\rangle = \{k\frac{n}{q_1} : k \in\mathbb{Z}\}$ by definition. 
So $\frac{n}{q_1}$ is the positive integer such that $[k][\frac{n}{q_1}] = n$.  We can see $n$ is a multiple of $[\frac{n}{q_1}]$. similarly, $H' = \{ p\frac{n}{q_2} : p \in\mathbb{Z}\}$. And $\frac{n}{q_2}$ is the positive integer such that $[p][\frac{n}{q_2}] = n$. So we can see $n$ is also a multiple of $[\frac{n}{q_2}]$.

Can anyone please help me. I don't really know how to continue. 
I would really appreciate any help.
Thank you

Comment: Are you familiar with Lagrange's theorem?

Comment: ^ Lagrange's theorem covers one direction of the implication.

Comment: No, we have not learned that yet. Might there be another way?

Comment: Have you heard of the fundamental theorem of cyclic groups?

Comment: Yes, I think that it is "every subgroup of a cyclic group is a cyclic group". And every subgroup of Zn is cyclic.

Comment: I can't understand how the OP hasn't heard of Lagrange's theorem, one of the most basic, simplest of all theorems about orders in finite group (and which is taught *usually* very early in any group theory course), yet he has heard of the Fundamental Theorem for Cyclic Groups...

Comment: The F.T. for cyclic groups could in fact be best written as: a  finite group of order $\;n\;$ is cyclic iff it has one **unique** subgroup of order $\;d\;$, for **any** divisor $\;d\;$ of $\;n\;$. In this case, it clearly follows every subgroup of a finite cyclic group is cyclic itself.

Comment: Every class is different.

Comment: $1$ generates $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.  What do you think generates $H$ and $H'$.  You cite that they're cyclic in the comments.  Is there a way for any (nonzero) element of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ to have order not dividing $n$?  If so, what are the possibilities for the orders of potential generators of $H$ and $H'$?