# Subgroups, orders and divisibility.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that for any two subgroups $H$ and $J$ of $\Bbb Z_n$, we have $H ⊆ J$ iff $|H| \text{ divides }|J|$.

Attempt: Suppose $H ⊆ J$, then we know there are generators that generate $H$ and $J$ since they are cyclic. So  let $H = <a>$, and $J = <b>$, then $b|a$ by proposition 2.21. We also know by proposition that the order of $|H| = n/d$, where $d$ is the smallest of positive integers $a$, such that $H = <a>$. Likewise, let $|J| = n/d'$, where $d'$ is the smallest of positive integers $b$, such that $J = <b>$. 
Thus $d|H| = n$ and $d'|J| = n$.

Can someone please help me. I don't know how to continue. And I need to submit my homework soon.
Thank you.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707641/subgroups-of-zn-order-divisibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $H\subseteq J$, there is an $m$ such that $bm=a$, in fact this $m$ is the smallest integer such that $bm\in H$. Then $|J|=n/b=mn/a=m|J|$.

Conversely, if $|H|=n/a$ divides $|J|=n/b$, then $b$ divides $a$.